# How to detect EdgePan Gesture SwiftUI

Tags: swift, gesture, swiftui

Im trying to recognize a EdgePan from the left in SwiftUI. I know there are some gestures but haven't been able to apply them to the whole screen. (Tried with DragGesture).
Is it possible to implement an EdgePan in SwiftUI? 
Or how can I use DragGesture to do the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible with a `DragGesture`.

`DragGesture` has a `startLocation` property, which is a `CGPoint`. From this, you can detect where the gesture started, and using this you can determine if it started from an edge.

Take your existing `DragGesture`, and in the `.onChanged` closure, pass in `gesture`, and find the start location with `gesture.startLocation`. Since you want to detect an edge, you'll want the `x` property of `gesture.startLocation`.

It looks like this:

```
DragGesture()
    .onChanged({gesture in
        if gesture.startLocation.x < CGFloat(100.0){
            print("edge pan")
        }
     }
)
```

Comment: Oh I forgot the post :D Yeah I did the same thing but with `.onEnded`

Comment: Works great only issue is that it doesn't take into consideration the direction itself.
Say you are on the left edge and swipe up, this would consider that as an edge pan but we want horizontal movement.
I wrapped the print in this code that makes sure the angle is +45* or -45* which is to me close enough to be horizontal... 
                            let slope = abs((gesture.startLocation.y - gesture.location.y)/(gesture.startLocation.x - gesture.location.x))
                            if slope < 1 {
                                  print("edge pan")
                            }